# Defining objects using OBJECT-TYPE and using in 2 different applications

Tags: snmp, rfc, mib, snmpd, ietf

I am writing and implementing some MIB files. I want to implement a bunch of objects in a Base-MIB and reuse it in multiple projects. One way is to copy Base-MIB for each project and then import mibs of each project to corresponding Base-MIB (as examples in Cisco MIBs that CISCOWORKS-MIB imports ciscoworks from CISCO-SMI and use it as parent of MODULE-IDENTITY). In this way I should set a different parent to MODULE-IDENTITY of each copy of Base-MIB and having 2 different instance of Base-MIB.

But I want to do it in a reverse manner. It means importing a Base-MIB in mibs of each project and then use defined objects in Base-MIB as a sub-tree with different OIDs and different implementation specific to each project (So different values). But i have problem to assign different OIDs to objects inside Base-MIB. I want to use exactly the same Base-MIB instance for both projects.

Is there any syntax or rule to achieve this task?

regards.

Comment: There is no such thing in SNMP MIB standard.

Comment: @LexLi I want to define a mib and reuse it in multiple projects (reusing it objects). but mib name must be unique. and in a hierarchical oid tree, I must rename all of mibs per project. is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: No such thing and never supported. You cannot avoid what is by design.